# What is the best practice or storing constants in SAPUI5?

Tags: sapui5

I wonder what's the best practice is for storing costants (strings, numbers or URIs) in SAPUI5. I guess it's not recommended to just put them in the views or controllers.  I'm thinking about to go with the i18n. or to create a viewmodel. or to create a new .json file. if it should be best practice to create a .json model for it, then would be the next question, where to put this .json file in the standard folder structure of a SAPUI5 project.

Comment: Well, it depends on what are you going to use these URLs for? If you want to show them in controls, you can check the article about whitelist of URLS https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/91f3768f6f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070.html . But if you want to use them as constants, you can add the json or js file under the 'model' folder.

Comment: white list is a nice feature that it didn't know. may be handy at sometime in the future. yes, want to use them as constants. guess, .json in the model is one good option.

Comment: yep, you can even set this JSON model with constans as a global named model, so you'll be able to access it whenever you want from controllers or from views, does not matter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SAPUI5 is based off the [Asynchronous Module Definition](https://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html#amd) so we can simply create a module definition that houses all of our constants, much like similiar patterns we see in other scaffolds like CRA and angular-cli.

So we could create a file called `Constants.js` in our `webapp` folder and then add our URLs and other constants as such:

```js
// webapp/Constants.js
sap.ui.define([],
function() {
    'use strict';

    var constants = {
        BASE_URL: 'http://localhost:8080',
        SOME_API_PATH: '/api/some',
        REQUEST_HEADERS: {
            'X-XSRF-TOKEN': 'something-else'
        },
        ANOTHER_CONSTANT: 'something'
    };

    return constants;
});
```

We then can import the constants wherever we need to by adding it to the dependency array:

```js
// SomeController.js
sap.ui.define([
    '<PROJECT_NAME>/Constants'
], function(Constants) {
  console.info(Constants.BASE_URL);
});
```

`.env` Files would also be an option for environmental based constants, however, that's outside the scope of your question I think.

Answer (score -1):

currently I use a local `sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel` to store static URLs.

**folder structure**

```
webapp
--controller
--i18n
--localService
--model
--test
--util // into the util folder goes the url.json
----url.json
--view
```

**url.json**

```
[{
  "my_url_name": "my_url"
},
{
  "my_other_url_name": "my_other_url"
}]
```

**View.controller.js**

```
...
onInit: function(oEvent) {
  ...

  // set model to view
  var sPath = jQuery.sap.getModulePath("myAppNameSpace.util", "/url.json");
  var oModel = new JSONModel(sPath);
  this.getView().setModel(oModel, "url");

  // use model
  var sMyUrl = this.getView().getModel("url").getProperty("/my_url_name");

  ...
}
...
```